# MariaDb replication (Master with private ip)

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, replication, database-replication

I was trying to replicate between master server and slave server, but master server are private ip and having different location with slave server. Is there have any method like replication, that able to replicate.

Comment: With private IP i geuss you mean the ((W)LAN) IP adresses that begin with 10, 172, and 192?

Comment: @RaymondNijland Yes

Comment: If the Slave has a public IP, perhaps you can set up an SSL link.